# Fixing Wyvern/CKEditor

Tags: add-on, fieldtype, ckeditor, wyvern

I have run into an issue with the addon Wyvern where the field in the publish/edit pages doesn't display as described in this support ticket: https://boldminded.com/support/ticket/773

I figured my best option to resolve the issue is to follow the first response and reinstall Wyvern:

> You might have to set all your Wyvern fields to textarea, uninstall, then reinstall Wyvern and assign the fields back to Wyvern.

But before I do that I want to be sure that this process is safe. It would mean converting about a dozen fields to Textarea (Rich Text) and back. Would changing the filetype strip out anything that might be unique to Wyvern, or would it just leave the source code intact until Wyvern was reinstalled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the fieldtype won't strip out data. Internally Wyvern, Wygwam, or any WYSIWYG editor just saves the data to a normal text column in the database. Changing the type to textarea just ensures that it contains the same blob of text that contains html, but nothing enacts on it or tries to modify it. So in short, yes you are safe in doing this.

Always backup your database though.

Comment: Yes of course about the backup, I just wanted to triple check because although I was fairly certain of the answer I still felt I should triple check as I don't want to carelessly cause a client issues because all their articles become corrupt or something. Thank you.